# animate div with image in time interval

Tags: image, html, jquery-animate

The following is my div boxes.

```
<div id="one1" class="f"></div>
    <div id="one2" class="f"></div>

   <div id="two1" class="s"></div>
    <div id="two2" class="s"></div>

   <div id="three1" class="c"></div>
    <div id="three2" class="c"></div>

   <div id="four1" class="d"></div>
    <div id="four2" class="d"></div>
```

The following is my style for div boxes.

```
#one1{width:114px; height:35px; background-image:url(about1.png); float:left; margin-left:10px;}
#one2{width:114px; height:35px; background-image:url(about-rollover.png); margin-left:10px; float:left}

#two1{width:114px; height:35px; background-image:url(about1.png); float:left; margin-left:10px;}
#two2{width:114px; height:35px; background-image:url(about-rollover.png); margin-left:10px; float:left}

#three1{width:114px; height:35px; background-image:url(about1.png); float:left; margin-left:10px;}
#three2{width:114px; height:35px; background-image:url(about-rollover.png); margin-left:10px; float:left}

#four1{width:114px; height:35px; background-image:url(about1.png); float:left; margin-left:10px;}
#four2{width:114px; height:35px; background-image:url(about-rollover.png); margin-left:10px; float:left}
```

I need this boxes to change the image in certain time level.First image change the image in certain time interval. After this finishes next change the image. after fourth image changing i need to start first image. If mouse over the images means all time interval must clear. Please suggest me any ideas.

Comment: You could `animate()` function of jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: did you tried anything? show us your code

Answer (score 0):

You may try using jquery plugins such as [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/). They have nice transition effects and